How can I implement Lazy loading of child rows in Simple Tree Table plugin
The problem with simple tree table plugin is that it works perfectly fine when all the rows including child rows and grandchild rows are preloaded , which consumes some space , especially when the child rows are not even demanded by the users (but still it exists in the memory ) , so what I want is the collapse and expand(of child rows) feature of simple. tree.table.js but the child rows are only loaded when it is  demanded , that is when users explicitly clicks on the parent rows .
I tried to load the child rows when the parent row is clicked , basically an AJAX request to the backend to get all the child rows , and append it like parentRow.after(childrow); and then reinitialize the simpleTreeTable plugin  $('#SubWork').simpleTreeTable({}); but the simpleTreeTable is not working with the lazy loaded child row.
